# PPO Boid agent not learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines, multi-agent

I have  a custom Boid flocking environment in OpenAI Gym using PPO from StableBaselines3. I wanted it to achieve flocking similar to [Reynold's model (Video)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/171TRU9uN4XGxpYidldbQ1Swsf6iZp4om/view?usp=drive_link) or close enough, but it ISN'T learning.

[Reynold's model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktuRb.png)

[My Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ltWM2rDwZU36ipZTDBqLHlCalKdQFk55/view?usp=drive_link)

My results after 100000 timesteps of training:

[My boids](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jAlGrGmpt2nUspBtoZcN7yJLHFQe4CAy/view?usp=drive_link)

[TensorBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HcX5.png)

I have adjusted the `calculate_reward` my model uses to be similar in reward, to encourage Reynold's model like behavior, but  can't see any apparent improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran it for 2Million, I am able to see that they all now just move away.

Two insights, Training time was too less and reward function needs to be modified.

2Million Training, 3000 steps run
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10-VSBmoxZfyO_KTS2a-7VWIWQSwggg9A/view?usp=drive_link